# Change prompt server sided

Tags: actions-on-google

I am starting to work myself into aog. I use the SDK and the WebSimulator only right now. What I am trying to achieve is to change the prompt I set before, e.g. because I have new information available. I tried the following which fails:

```
let inputPrompt = assistant.buildInputPrompt(true, '<speak>1+1=3 Agree?</speak>',['I didn\'t hear a number', 'If you\'re still there, what\'s the number?', 'What is the number?']);
assistant.ask(inputPrompt);
let inputPrompt2 = assistant.buildInputPrompt(true, '<speak>Sorry! 1+1=2 Agree?</speak>',['I didn\'t hear a number', 'If you\'re still there, what\'s the number?', 'What is the number?']);
assistant.ask(inputPrompt2);
```

Only the first prompt is presented and then - only after the user responded - the second one.

Is it possible at all to change the prompt server sided? How can it be done? Or is there maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `assistant.ask()` method will send the prompt to the user *and then wait for a response*.

If you're trying to send something to the user, and then send something else before they have replied, you're not able to do this currently using Actions. That would be more like a notification or an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there is a way, because using the MS Bot framework it is possible to do so and I think it would be a nice enhancement for Actions as well.